# Validity and Satisfiability problem.

Tags: logic, satisfiability

Formula F is equivalent to formula G iff

A) F IFF G is valid
B) F IFF NOT(G) is not valid
C) F XOR G satisfiable
D) F XOR G is not satisfiable

I have been told solution D is correct.

How is this statement correct?
Statement: Formula F is equivalent to formula G iff F XOR G is not satisfiable.

I know that if two formulas are equivalent then they are both valid(F<-->G)
. However, I don't understand how F XOR G not being satisfiable would apply here. When you XOR, the result true whenever an odd number of the inputs are true and is false whenever an even number of inputs are true. So it could never be valid or never "not satisfiable", right?

Comment: Answer A is also correct.  See the answer by @MauroALLEGRANZA for why D is correct.

Comment: I thought so. That's why I ruled out choice D. But I see now why it is correct too.

Comment: The Rolling Stones have a song about being "not satisfiable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [XOR Truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Truth_table).

To say that $F \text { XOR } G$ is **not** satisfiable means that it is always FALSE.

But, due to the corresponding truth table, the formula is always FALSE only when either $F$ and $G$ are both TRUE or they are both FALSE.

And two frmulas $F$ and $G$ are [equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) when either they are both TRUE or both FALSE (alternatively, when $F \Leftrightarrow G$ is *valid* or *tautological*).

Comment: Your last comment was the lightbulb I needed. Thank you.